# VSCode Python adding extra space after % on print when save

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying Python with VSCode and it is giving me a headache with formatting. I have te following code:

```
import os
filePath = "get-file-size.py"

try:
    size = os.path.getsize(filePath)

except OSError:
    print("Path '%s' does not exist or is not accesible", %filePath)
    sys.exit()

print("File size (in bytes): ", size)
```

VSCode gives me the following error:

> invalid syntax (, line 10)

This error happens because it adds an extra space after % in the except print statement as below:

```
print("Path '%s' does not exist or is not accesible", % filePath)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this? I am pretty sure it is because a formatter, but how, when, which one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Vscode Python extension supports source code formatting using autopep8 by default but it can change if you have installed any other formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the comma before the percent sign:

```py
print("Path '%s' does not exist or is not accesible" % filePath)
```

The percent sign is the formatting operator. It takes a string on the left and stuff to insert to the string on the right, it's not a separate argument of the print function.

Also, it's better to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```py
print("Path '{}' does not exist or is not accesible".format(filePath))
```

or if you're using python 3.6 and above, use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```py
print(f"Path '{filePath}' does not exist or is not accesible")
```

You can read more about it [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).

Comment: `'%s'` but the quotes I think its not necessary

Comment: Thank you!!!!! str.format and/or f-strings did the job

Comment: I assumed the quotes were to surround the path in the message you print, oh well